# How can i import a png file as base64 string without any new library and config on vue-cli project?

Tags: vue.js

I have tried the build-in url-loader as the following, but the imported base64 string is malformed.

```
imoprt myPngFile from 'url-loader!@/assets/myPngFile.png';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the png is malformed because the url-loader is executed on the wrong png.
Firstly, the png is executed by vue configed file-loader.
Then, the url-loader loads the result from file-loader.

Add !! as prefix will fix the problem.

```
import myPngFile from '!!url-loader!@/assets/myPngFile.png';
```

Reference:

[Webpack inline loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline)